# How to run Rails SystemTest with in-memory database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I setup `:memory:` database for test environment

```yaml
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: ":memory:"
```

and always run db migration when SystemTest setup

```rb
require "test_helper"

class ApplicationSystemTestCase < ActionDispatch::SystemTestCase
  driven_by :selenium, using: :firefox, screen_size: [1400, 1400]

  setup do
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(adapter: 'sqlite3', database: ':memory:')
    ActiveRecord::Schema.verbose = false
    load "#{Rails.root.to_s}/db/schema.rb"
  end
```

i debugged and saw the migration worked ok. However, after the browser is launched, it looks like the Rails app database is reset so the test throw the error `SQLite3::SQLException: no such table`

Even i tried migrate db on the test case like below, it still failed due to above reason.

```rb
test "visiting the index" do
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(adapter: 'sqlite3', database: ':memory:')
  ActiveRecord::Schema.verbose = false
  load "#{Rails.root.to_s}/db/schema.rb"

  @task = Task.create!(..) # OK
  
  # FAILED
  visit tasks_url
  assert_selector "h1", text: "Tasks"
end
```

In case of normal db setup, it works OK. So i guess when Capybara launch the browser, the :memory: db is reset.

How could i setup `:memory:` db for Rails SystemTest ?
Thanks !!!

Comment: Is `establish_connectio` step absolutely necessary? I think rails should set up a connection when starting the app, maybe you have two different connections that have two separate in memory databases and those can't be shared between connections.

Comment: @Grzegorz thank! it's unnecessary, the migration still work without it, however the error still there when i remove it.

Answer (score 0):

i come up with a cheating way: migrating `:memory:` db at the first time Capybara launch the browser each test case, to do that, i extend the `ApplicationController` in test environment like so

```rb
# test_helper.rb
 ...
class ApplicationController
  before_action :migrate_db

  def migrate_db
    if in_memory_db?
      # each time Capybara `visit` is called
      # load and seed db if the :memory: db is reset
      begin
        task_count = Task.count
      rescue => e
        load "#{Rails.root}/db/schema.rb"
      ensure
        # seed memory db
        if task_count.nil? || task_count.zero?
          Task.create!(...)
        end
      end
    end
  end

  # copy from https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activerecord/test/cases/helper.rb#L39
  private def in_memory_db?
    ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters.const_defined?(:SQLite3Adapter) &&
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.is_a?(ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters.const_get(:SQLite3Adapter)) &&
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.db_config.database == ":memory:"
  end
end
```